# Multiple Columns and Joins , SQL Server Studio 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2016

I have an "Employee" table. I have a "Team" table with four columns, each column holding a int ID. Each ID represents an Employee. (rubbish data probably from Northwind database)

I would like do a Query which returns a Table with the ID and a concatenation of the Employee data. 
I have been able to do it with CoordinatorID, but don't know how to get multiple columns.

I would like to do what was done for CoordinatorID for EstimatorID, ProjectManagerID,   & MarketingSalesmanID.

I can't upload and image, but there is a link to an image of my SQL Server window which should help clarify what I am trying to do.

Additionally, I doubt I am doing it right anyway. So if anyone can show me an example that I can study I would greatly appreciate it. I don't mind starting from scratch... Simple example is appreciated. I am still learning...

**Employee db**

ID  FirstName   LastName    Title

1   Nancy   Davolio Sales Representative

2   Andrew  Fuller  Vice President, Sales

3   Janet   Leverling   Sales Representative

**Team db**

ID  TeamName    CoordinatorID   EstimatorID ProjectManagerID    MarketingSalesmanID

1   Red 7   2   8   6

2   Green   1   7   3   3

3   Blue    9   5   3   4

```
SELECT TOP (3) [Employee].[TeamTbl].[TeamName], [Employee].[TeamTbl].[CoordinatorID],
CONCAT( [Employee].[EmployeeTbl].[FirstName],' ', [Employee].[EmployeeTbl].[LastName],', ', [Employee].[EmployeeTbl].[Title]) As CoordinatorIDName
FROM [Employee].[TeamTbl]
INNER JOIN [Employee].[EmployeeTbl] ON [Employee].[TeamTbl].[CoordinatorID]=[Employee].[EmployeeTbl].[ID];
```

[Sql Server Image if it helps make it clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGgno.png)

Comment: If you are trying to make more columns, just do what you did for Coordinator, and do more joins on the other tables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the Employee table multiple times using different aliases:

```
SELECT TOP (3) 
    [Employee].[TeamTbl].[TeamName], 
    CONCAT( c.[FirstName],' ', c.[LastName],', ', c.[Title]) As CoordinatorName
    CONCAT( e.[FirstName],' ', e.[LastName],', ', e.[Title]) As EstimatorName
    CONCAT( p.[FirstName],' ', p.[LastName],', ', p.[Title]) As ProjectManagerName
    CONCAT( m.[FirstName],' ', m.[LastName],', ', m.[Title]) As MarketingSalesmanName
FROM 
    [Employee].[TeamTbl]
INNER JOIN 
    [Employee].[EmployeeTbl] c ON [Employee].[TeamTbl].[CoordinatorID]=c.[ID]
INNER JOIN 
    [Employee].[EmployeeTbl] e ON [Employee].[TeamTbl].[EstimatorID]=e.[ID]
INNER JOIN 
    [Employee].[EmployeeTbl] p ON [Employee].[TeamTbl].[ProjectManagerID]=p.[ID]
INNER JOIN 
    [Employee].[EmployeeTbl] m ON [Employee].[TeamTbl].[MarketingSalesmanID]=m.[ID]
```

Comment: Nice solution but what is the top(3) doing?

Comment: It takes the top three rows only, it was in the asker's code so I assume they only want three records.

Comment: This comment was directed to the user. The user probably wants an order by in there somehow unless its just for development.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I need to go through and understand it, but yes this is what I was trying to do. "Top(3)" was only there so that I could display a small quantity for the image that was used to clarify my question.